# Primeng Angular change p-dialog background color

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I've been struggling to change the background color of the dialog based on a condition.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-6ypbjg)

changeColor is the variable I am checking if true. Works for changing background color for other tags. Assuming maybe some sort of further override is required for the dialogs. All I want is some sort of overlay on it, changing the color along the lines of this.

I've tried inline, global css styling. Even wrapping the dialog content in a div with styling has weird behaviour.

**Updated Code:**

[Stackblitz Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-51jm3z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the dialog content, you will need to use `styleClass` to set a class on the dialog and then style the inner elements with `.p-dialog-title`, `.p-dialog-content` and `.p-dialog-footer`.

Here's what the code would look like.

```html
<!-- template -->
<p-dialog
  header="Long Content"
....
  [styleClass]="changeColor ? 'lightgray' : ''"
>
```

```css
:host ::ng-deep .lightgray .p-dialog-header {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
:host ::ng-deep .lightgray .p-dialog-content {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
:host ::ng-deep .lightgray .p-dialog-footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-9d46q4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

If instead, you want to have a mask layer behind the dialog, you can set `[modal]="true"` on the dialog to have it show a transparent layer behind the dialog.

Comment: Tried my first attempt with your suggestions - see updated stackblitz (still same color). All I want is the white background of the dialog to be a different color. Unless you're saying I have to apply the styling to all the content in my dialog too?

Comment: @Waz As the other answer mentioned, you are missing the link to app.component.css in your stackblitz. I've added a link with the fixed stackblitz and included the full css you would need to change just the background on the dialog.

Comment: @Waz Can you also include your previous code in the question itself? Now that the stackblitz has been updated, anybody new would not understand what the actual question was.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the import of the .css file into component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
```